How to prevent Spring Boot from handling the http range header itself?
I have the following rest controller and method, mapped to a GET request:
@RestController
public class FileController {

@GetMapping(
      path = "/file",
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
  public Resource getFile(@RequestHeader(name = HttpHeaders.RANGE) String range) {
     //..some logic
     Resource resource = myService.produceResource(range) //this produces a ByteArrayResource
     return resource;
  }
}

When a client passes http range header, it is respected and a partial response is returned. So far I've done nothing to make this possible, I'm guessing Spring (or embedded Tomcat?) is automatically handling this.
The problem is, I need to pass the range parameter to myService which in turn calls another application's REST API, passing the range header alongside. The other application also handles the range header and returns correct partial response, which causes my app to try to partition an already partitioned resource.
I don't want to tell the client to send the range header differently to avoid this, so how can I stop Spring (embedded Tomcat?) from automatically handling the header?
